# Consulta css para ciertos tags

Tags: html, css, materialize, svg

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <title>aprobado</title>
                <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
                <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
                <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
                <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
                <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
                <style type="text/css"></style>
            </head>
            <body ng-controller="main">
                <div id="chart" style="width:100%; height:400px; padding: 150px 0px;"></div>
                <div id="container"></div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

El problema es de que cuando agrego las librerías de `materialize` éstas sobreescriben algunos estilos de highcharts. Además se agrega el svg diferente.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que las librerías mencionadas (las de `materialize`) sólo afecten a determinados tags?

Answer (score 3):

Conozco 3 maneras que te pueden servir, aunque la **3** la desaconsejo:

**1. El orden de importación de los CSS es importante**

Si tienes 2 CSS, el que esté definido más **abajo** tiene prioridad en sus definiciones **siempre y cuándo éstas sean igual de específicas**.
Para poner un ejemplo claro y cogiendo tus definiciones:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
```

Si los definimos en este orden (lo que tienes actualmente) eso significa que si, por ejemplo, ambos definen:

1. CSS 1

   ```
   body .p {
       width: 100%;
   }
   ```
2. CSS 2

   ```
   body .p {
       width: 50%;
   }
   ```

Sólo le hará caso al CSS 2 porqué está definido más abajo y son igual de específicos en su tag `body .p`.

**2. Definir los tags de manera más específica.**

Si tienes 2 CSS el que esté definido más **abajo** tiene prioridad en sus definiciones **siempre y cuándo éstas sean igual de específicas**, con esto de específico, me refiero a:

1. CSS 1

   ```
   body .p {
       width: 100%;
   }
   ```
2. CSS 2

   ```
    body {
        width: 50%;
    }
   ```

Entonces, cómo el CSS 1 es **más específico** que el CSS 2, todos los elementos `p` del Body tendrán el 100% de width aunque el body que no sean elementos `p` serán al 50% de width.

**3. Definir los CSS con !important**

**No recomendable** - Utilizar el tag `important` en CSS normalmente implica *desajustes* y *problemas* en un futuro, ya que siempre tienen prioridad y cuándo gestionas más de 1 CSS puede ser un problema encontrar por qué un estilo no te está haciendo caso.

Si en cualquier tag de CSS pones un `!important` le dará prioridad por delante de cualquier cosa.

Con el ejemplo de antes:

1. CSS 1

   ```
   body .p {
       width: 100% !important;
   }
   ```
2. CSS 2

   ```
   body .p {
       width: 50%;
   }
   ```

Aunque el orden es importante, el tag `!important` hace que el CSS 1 tenga prioridad sobre cualquier otro CSS en este caso concreto.

---

En conclusión, si ponemos **primero** la librería `materialize` tendrá menos prioridad que lo que venga luego, pero **sólo si los tags són menos específicos o iguales**. Si los tags són más específicos que en tu segundo CSS, la primera librería tendrá prioridad. Si defines !important en **todos** los tags que quieres que tengan prioridad también lo tienes solucionado (pero es lo menos recomendable hacerlo así).

Comment: Hola si ,las 2 primeras no me funcionan , habia pensado con important , pero como un muchas clases , quizas usando less o stylus? ,aunque no se usarlo todavía-.

Comment: No puede ser que no te funcione. Eso es así tal y cómo se explica en al documentación de W3schools. Fíjate bien a ver si hay algo que te has saltado. Desaconsejo MUCHO utilizar el !important... Y no hay otra manera de dar prioridad.

Comment: En lugar de poner un LINK al css descárgatelos y asñi los podrás ver y editar.

Comment: No recomendaría descargar y editar los archivos CSS porque complica la actualización y es difícil de mantener. Mejor crear un nuevo archivo CSS que sobreescriba los estilos siguiendo las indicaciones de la respuesta